# Invalid Credentials - Google plus access token error

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I have an issue with Google plus access token. It is giving me "Invalid Credentials" error message sometimes, sometimes the same token show as active.

**Following are the steps**

The user confirms permission to access Google account with selected scopes.

The refresh token and access token is retrieved and saved to long time storage.

Used to refresh the token when ever needed by using stored refresh token

But sometimes I've experienced strange behaviour:
Requests to Google APIs return Invalid Credentials (401) error. Refreshing the access token (using the stored refresh token) does not work.

**Access token refresh method** 
Using googleapis npm module to refresh token
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis

```
 oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken(function (err, tokens) {
            if (err) {
              console.log('error', err);
            }
            console.log('access tokens', tokens.access_token); // Access token 
            console.log('refresh tokens', tokens.refresh_token); // Refresh token       
        });
```

**Questions:** 
What can be the reason for this behaviour?

Does this behaviour related to with any google api rate limit? because the same token works sometimes and not other-times.

Is there a way to validate the refresh token?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you refresh your access token using refresh token, you will given by new access token.The refresh token has no expiry. You can use the refresh token as many as possible for refreshing the access token

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i have edited my question to include my token refresh method, could you please check it. Every time am calling a refresh function and using the new refresh and access token for later use.

Comment: The Google api provide a single refresh token while you first authorize. If you authorize using the same account, you will not get any refresh token. The google api refresh token has no expiry. So you can use it as lifelong. The only expiry is for access token . I have edited my answer too.

Comment: Thank you prakash, thanks for your information. Am doing exactly like the way you said. I used to refresh access token every day using refresh token and stored both access token and refresh token in my database. Its working sometimes but some times the access token giving "Invalid Credentials".

Comment: May be the access token is not updating in your db.